# background body

Tags: html, css

Можно ли задать

```
body {background: url(../img/img1) no-repeat;}
```

или создать обертку внутри body , в которую мы положим header, main. (footer нет на странице)

Как будет правильнее? Картинка на всю страницу в моем случае, и кстати как правильнее задать размеры? ведь если их не задать, бэкграунд не будет отображаться, если в обертке не будет содержимого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли задать

можно.

> Кстати как правильнее задать размеры?

```
background-size: [ <значение> | <проценты> | auto ] | cover | contain.
```

> Бэкграунд не будет отображаться, если в обертке не будет содержимого.

если задать body то всегда будет отображаться.  А если не body то просто пропиши размеры блока.

Comment: Короче ничего страшного если тупо пропишу размеры обертке, оберну в нее содержимое хедера и мэйна, так?